# Application for typing matrices on OSX (or online)

Tags: matrices, mac

Is there an application (on OSX) where you could create a matrix with the help of a graphical interface and that would produce automatically the corresponding LaTeX code?

PS: I would be also interested in an online solution.

Comment: I found this: http://www.tablesgenerator.com

Comment: since you need to type the numbers anyway and the only markup you need is `&` between the cells, what do you want the graphical application to do that couldn't be done with a text editor (or even notepad?)

Comment: The graphical application would help me to design big matrices more quickly. I though this existed and was looking for help to find again such an application.

Answer (score 1):

Texstudio/Texmaker (both cross platform) have a wizard (see [User manual Texstudio "Inserting a table"](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION18) for tables, matrices etc, by giving the number of rows and columns.